# JPEG parameter struct mismatch: library thinks size is 624, caller expects 656

Tags: go, tesseract, libjpeg, mupdf

I'm writing a PDF to text solution using OCR in Golang.

The libraries I employed are [Gosseract](https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract) and [Go-Fitz](https://github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz)

The program works until I'm trying to load an image from memory with Gosseract:

```golang
func ProcessDoc(file []byte) (string, error) {
    var text strings.Builder

    client := gosseract.NewClient()

    doc, err := fitz.NewFromMemory(file)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return "", nil
    }

    for n := 0; n < doc.NumPage(); n++ {
        img, err := doc.Image(n)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return "", err
        }

        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

        err = jpeg.Encode(buf, img, nil)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return "", err
        }

        client.SetImageFromBytes(buf.Bytes())
        
        res, err := client.Text()
        
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        text.WriteString(res)
    }
    return text.String(), nil
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
JPEG parameter struct mismatch: library thinks size is 624, caller expects 656
Error in pixReadStreamJpeg: internal jpeg error
Error in pixReadMemJpeg: pix not read
Error in pixReadMem: jpeg: no pix returned
```

After a lot of searching, I learned there was the possibility of `libleptonica` or `mupdf` using different versions of `jpeglib.h`. But there's only one instance of that file in the whole system.

I should also note that I compiled `libjpeg` from source and then `libmupdf` and `libleptonica` to use that version of `libjpeg` to avoid any form of conflicts but it still returns the Struct Mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling mupdf from source?

By default mupdf includes it's own version of libjpeg - it is possible that mupdf compiled against it's own version and libleptonica against the system version.

Comment: Hi, Yes I'm Compiling From Source And I Put The Source Files Of The Libjpeg I Manually Compiled And Installed Into The Thirdparty Folder Of Mupdf, So I'd Think It's Using The Same One As The System.